# A conjecture of Montgomery: reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

In the answer to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/834/arithmetic-progressions-without-small-primes/1498#comment364029_1498), engelbret mentions "a conjecture of H. L. Montgomery (not the one on pair correlations, another one), which implies both the GRH and the Elliott-Halberstam conjecture.". My question is : what does this conjecture says, and where is it stated ? I am also interested in any references that would discuss that conjecture.

Comment: I just saw the following question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115438/is-there-a-montgomerys-conjecture-for-dirichlet-characters-and-artin-representa by you discussing this very conjecture.

Comment: yes, I just noticed it now as well, strange...

Comment: Lucia, Carlo, somehow I didn't realize that the conjecture you mention, and that indeed I knew, was implying both GRH and Elliot-Halberstam, hence was the conjecture engelbert was talking about. This was stupid of me. I kind of imagined that there was a deeper conjecture of Montgomery, on the distribution of zero's on the critical line, which would imply and provide an explanation for the you guys mention. Somehow I am not completely convinced by the answer to my question 115438.

Answer (score 5):

discussion: [Limitations to the equidistribution of primes](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Equidist1.pdf) (Friedlander and Granville, 1989) and [Small gaps between prime numbers](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-01/S0273-0979-06-01142-6/S0273-0979-06-01142-6.pdf) (Soundararajan, 2007) (page 16).

the sources to Montgomery are

*Topics in multiplicative number theory* (Springer, 1971)

Proc. Symp. Pure Math. **28**, 307 (1976)

Answer (score 5):

I think the conjecture you have in mind is that for an arithmetic progression $a\pmod q$ with $(a,q)=1$ and $x\ge q$
$$ 
\Psi(x;q,a) = \frac{x}{\phi(q)} + O\Big(\frac{x^{\frac 12+\epsilon}}{\sqrt{q}}\Big).
$$ 
This is stronger than GRH which has the error $O(x^{\frac 12+\epsilon})$, and just summing the errors over all $q\le x^{1-\epsilon}$ you get the Elliott-Halberstam conjecture as well.